# TikZ foreach and relative node positioning

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, foreach, tikz-positioning

I want to use a `foreach` loop to position tikz nodes below each other.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary[positioning]
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (n1){First};
  \foreach \x in {2,...,6}{%
    \pgfmathparse{\x-1}%
    \node [below = of n\pgfmathresult](n\x)  {\x};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: numbers drifting to the right]

Why are the numbers drifting to the right!?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`\pgfmathparse` evaluates to a float number: 1.0, 2.0, ...
Then, you get `below = of n1.0`. The `.0` is an border anchor, meaning the border at an angle of 0°, the same as `n.east`. This explains the shift to the right. The lower node's center is placed below the upper node's right side.

The `.0` can be stripped by `\pgfmathtruncatemacro`, for example:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary[positioning]
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (n1){First};
  \foreach \x in {2,...,6}{%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\lastx}{\x - 1}
    \node [below = of n\lastx](n\x)  {\x};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

An alternative is key `remember` in the `\foreach` loop to remember the previous value without the need to calculate it:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary[positioning]
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (n1){First};
  \foreach \x [remember=\x as \lastx (initially 1)] in {2,...,6}{%
    \node [below = of n\lastx](n\x)  {\x};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. Thank you for nice explanation.

Comment: `remember` is precisely what I want! I was trying to do it myself with `\def` but that obviously doesn't work. Thanks for the explanation too.

Answer (score 4):

[Zarko](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/645856/73317) and [Heiko Oberdiek](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/645859/73317) and explained the reason of the problem (`\pgfmathparse` producing a floating point result unless told otherwise; `.0` being interpreted as a Ti*k*Z anchor specification: 0° = `east` anchor).

Here are some other possibilities that don't bet on `\node` not overwriting `\pgfmathresult`:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (n1) {First};
  \foreach \x in {2,...,6}
    {
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xMinusOne}{\x-1}
      \node [below = of n\xMinusOne] (n\x) {\x};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (n1) {First}
    foreach[evaluate=\x as \xMinusOne using int(\x - 1)] \x in {2,...,6}
      { node[below = of n\xMinusOne] (n\x) {\x} };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I knew there must be a smarter way to do this. Thanks for the pointers!

Answer (score 4):

Here's another possibility using tikz library `chains`:

```tex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[start chain=1 going below, nodes={on chain=1}]
    \node (n1) {First}
      foreach \x in {2,...,6}
        { node (n\x) {\x} };
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is a neat library. It doesn't work for my actual use case, but it's definitely a good solution for some circumstances.

Comment: @Seamus My pleasure ^_^

Answer (score 3):

You need node position you should calculate as `\pgfmathparse{int(\x-1)}%`, with out `int` coordinates are `n1.0` which are not valid format in your case (numbers after decimal point determine anchor on node border) for positioning of nodes in image.

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary[positioning]
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1ex]
  \node (n1) {First};
  \foreach \x in {2,...,6}{%
    \pgfmathparse{int(\x-1)}%
    \node [below = of n\pgfmathresult] (n\x)  {\x};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Nodes' position you can determne by defining new counter:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary[positioning]
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1ex]
  \node (n1) {First};
  \foreach \x [count=\y] in {2,...,6}{%
    \node [below = of n\y] (n\x)  {\x};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result is the same as before.

Comment: Ah great. That solves the problem, but now I'm still puzzled by why it sort of manages to position nodes below each other, even though the node names are invalid!?

Comment: The second solution is better because in the first one, `\pgfmathresult` might be overwritten by `\node` before it is used.